# How to add a string (title) at the end of the url with Django?

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I have the follow url:

```
http://mywebsite.com/post/1/ 

url(r'^guideline/(\d+)/?(?:.json)?$', perma_post, name="cv_perma")
```

How can I add an string at the end to display the title of the post 1? For example

```
http://mywebsite.com/post/1/THIS-IS-JUST-THE-TITLE/
```

Comment: You mean you want to fill in the title after the URL is loaded or expect the title to be found together with the ID? It's very dangerous tho; if you fixate this and change a title of the Post ID you will get unlinked URL slugs.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think is better to display it as a get parameter. On the other hand, how does stackoverflow do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title in the URL is part of the pattern, which may or may not be matched against the document slug in the view.

Something like:

```
url(r'^guideline/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', perma_post, name="cv_perma")
```

Then you could look for an object with both id and slug, or just the id and redirect to the correct URL if the slug does not match -which is what Stackoverflow does.